# Перенос бота вк на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, vkontakte-api, flask, pythonanywhere

Имеется бот для группы вк, на ноутбуке работает, все функции выполняет. Но нужно перенести его на pythonanywhere, а я абсолютно не знаю, как это сделать! Сейчас приём и отправка сообщений выглядит так :

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = 'здесь токен') 
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type ==  VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        send_message(event)    #функция отправки сообщения
```

Было бы хорошо переделать всё это под flask

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/326898/

Comment: @KABANPUNK Спасибо, помогло!